# how to develop android firmware?

Tags: android, linux, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-firmware

I need to create my own android firmware based on Honeycomb.

the problem is that I don't know how I suppose to do that.    I've searched on the web for some tutorials to help me getting started, but haven't found any.

can anyone link me to some tutorials, or give me some information about how to create android firmware?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marakana has some good tutorials/training courses for Android. 
I think the Android internals video may be a good start as this will tell you how Android actually works.

[Android Internals: Marakana](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0)

Comment: thanks. I'm going over the video right now. I'll mark the question as accepted latter, cause I'd like more pepole to write more answers..

Comment: Please keep updating the post with any other links you find so it becomes a good resource on stackoverflow for others.